# Which part is the door chime speaker on a Toyota?

Tags: electrical, toyota, door, speakers, accessories

I find this part and it says door buzzer. I'm afraid this is the one that sounds beeping instead of chiming.

[image: Taken from googling the internet]

Additionally, would it chime with the same intervals when connected directly to power?

I'm planning on bringing door ajar warning to an old car that doesn't have the warning sound. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Where did you find this? Do you have a part number? Do you have a schematic for the vehicle into which it was used?

Comment: I found this picture in eBay or Google, all of them is labeled as door chime and might come from keyword door buzzer. But I can't be sure if this item really what makes the famous ding ding ding chime. But I think I get your point. I need to get to the schematic first.. several items I see have number 89747-51010.